# How to disable any Tomcat filter within Springboot war?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, cors

I'm currently working on a SpringBoot 2 app which is going to be deployed on Tomcat 8. Everything is working perfectly when launching in SpringBoot mode but CORS requests are failing in WAR deployed mode.

Actually, I would like to simply turn off the Tomcat CORS filter that prevails on the SpringBoot app CORS filter. Then clients are never retrieving right headers.

After a lot of research, I have found several CORS configurations at Tomcat level but none that redirects to the app CORS config.

I tried to register one *org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter* bean on a foo URI but without success.

Based on a custom valve, one solution would be to reuse Springboot CORS config rules. But I'm still hoping for easier or more elegant way ?

Thanks for any feedback

[EDIT]

For reasons I still ignore, the issue described earlier is happening only when using Tomcat with IDE. I mean when I start Tomcat from Eclipse for example with my web app module, CORS requests are failing

But when I deploy the resulted WAR from the same wep app into the same Tomcat server, everything's just fine !

So until I find a solution, I guess Im going to launch with SpringBoot mode on DEV/LOCAL and check everything again with Tomcat before any release